# How to align vertically two figures in subcaption environment?

Tags: vertical-alignment, subcaption, subfig

As shown in the following code, I have two subfigures:

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[ht]
    \centering
       \begin{subfigure}{\textwidth}
        \centering
           \includegraphics[scale=1]{vel_ang_loop_per.eps}
           \caption{Componenti $p(t)$, $q(t)$ e $r(t)$ della velocità angolare.}
           \label{fig:p,q,r_loop_perf}
       \end{subfigure} \\[1cm]
 
       \begin{subfigure}{\textwidth}
           \centering
           \includegraphics[scale=1]{vel_trasl_loop_per.eps}
           \caption{Componenti $u(t)$, $v(t)$, $w(t)$ della velocità del   baricentro.}
           \label{fig:u,v,w_loop_perf}
       \end{subfigure}
     \caption{test}
\end{figure}


\end{document}
```

The problem is that they are not perfectly aligned vertically (as shown by dots that I drew in the image):
[image]

My figures files:
[first_fig](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1X_RI7PWeGlvefYxk32oP4dY8KexxtpzR/view?usp=sharing)
[second_fig](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1fjFOiUIdig6a9g0rTDMjXTD22pE3ZBuD/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Since I don't see your full pictures I can only guess, but the problem could come from the axis labels. you can try `\begin{subfigure}[r]{\textwidth}`. If it is not working maybe you can provide your figures.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Excelsior. I've added the two figures to my question.

Comment: Since the first picture have y-axis values over 100 and the second not, the dimensions did not match. Have you tried the `[r]` comand?

Comment: Would it be a option for you to use `pgfplots` to plot it in latex?

Comment: You may be best off re-creating the files `vel_ang_loop_per.eps` and `vel_trasl_loop_per.eps` so that (a) their overall widths are the same and (b) the positions of the graphs themselves also align.

Comment: @Excelsior, yes, I've added `[r]` comand but it does not work.

Comment: @Mico, I've created those image in Matlab with the same command:
''set(gcf,'position',[400, 200, 560, 315]); 
print('-depsc2','-r600',strcat('name_image','.eps'));"

Comment: @Giuseppe I opened your .eps and the problem is the margin at the right side. When you remove it, the alignment should be working

Comment: Well guys! I think I understand the problem! The two figures are correctly aligned but the same cannot be said for the y-axis because in the second figure we have values of numbers above 100 with respect to the first image. So this produce the not correct alignement of the vertical axis.
Actually, this is a false problem!

Comment: @Giuseppe I used inkscape to ungroup the picture and removed the background. There, you can also scale the pictures for your needs